# How to keep size of a DIV independent of window resizing AND zooming?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to keep the physical size of a DIV constant, even when the user zooms in/out, or resizes the browser window.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
<center>Hello world</center>

<div style="text-align:left;background-color:#474747; 
line-height:1.4;color:#a7a7a7;font-size:2vh;width:60vh;height:30vh;
bottom:0px;right:0px;margin:2vh;position:fixed;padding:1vh;">FixedDIV</div>
```

https://codepen.io/hexatomium/full/MWwNpzB

This almost fills my objective, except when vertically resizing the window.

Thanks for any ideas.

Note: Ideally I would like to make this work in Chrome and IE11.

Comment: Would be fatal. That is not possible because of accessibility settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API).

This will take one step further.

```
const update = (event) => {
    document.getElementById("size").style.width = window.visualViewport.width / 10 + 'px';
    document.getElementById("size").style.height = window.visualViewport.height / 10 + 'px';
    document.getElementById("size").innerHTML = window.visualViewport.width + 'px';
}
visualViewport.addEventListener('scroll', update);
visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', update);
addEventListener('scroll', update);
```

https://codepen.io/AvremiFriedman/pen/abOejZJ

It dont work good enough on code.

Try it on yor computer. You will get better results.